# extending ASP.net HelpPage Home

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've been using ASP.net HelpPages to generate documentation for my ApiControllers. Right now  the index for the help page is showing the name/path of the controller and a description of the controller.

```
CONTROLLER NAME
------------------------------------------------------------
Api                           Description
------------------------------------------------------------
GET  api/Admin/Users          Some vague description here.
POST api/Admin/Users          Another vague description here.
```

I would like to display more information regarding the controller on the index screen.

```
CONTROLLER NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Api                    Description          Permissions      Field2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
GET  api/Admin/Users   Description here.    Admin            48
POST api/Admin/Users   Description here.    Regular          92
```

In short I want to extend the view from the first view (just api/description) to the second view (extended).

**Edit:** I put breakpoints in ApiGroup.cshtml and HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.
cs and it appears that the rendering of the index page runs before the properties are added to the HelpPageApiModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the same method I used to add information to the individual pages for the controllers because the index page is rendered before the ApiModel is generated in HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.cs. Probably because they don't want to wait a couple eons for the index page to load.

To work around this, I added the logic directly to the ApiGroup.cshtml file. The additional parameters that I wanted to include on the index page were derived from attributes which can be accessed through the ApiDescription object.

This looks like:

(**ApiGroup.cshtml**)

```
@foreach (var api in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="api-name"><a href="@Url.Action("Api", "Help", new {apiId = api.GetFriendlyId()})">@api.HttpMethod.Method @api.RelativePath</a></td>
        <td class="api-documentation">
        @if (api.Documentation != null)
        {
            <p>@api.Documentation</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No documentation available.</p>
        }
        </td>
        <td class="api-Type1">
            @DisplayType1Information(api)
        </td>
        <td class="api-Type2">
            @DisplayType2Information(api)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here is an example of one of my helpers that holds the logic for the displayType1 information:

```
@helper DisplayType1Information(ApiDescription api)
{
    string typeOfType1 = "None";
    Type1 attribute =
        api.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Type1Attribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (attribute != null)
    {
        enum enumType = attribute.enumOfType1;
        typeOfType1 = enumType.ToString();
    }
    <p>@typeOfType1</p>
}
```

I'd imagine adding too much logic into a .cshtml file is a bad practice as it may slow down loading the page, but this didn't seem to have any effect on the page.